# Count multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have several mysql tables like this:

blogs

- entry_id
- member_d

articles

- entry_id
- member_d

posts

- entry_id
- member_d

I want to count the total entries by a specific member. I currently have this (while only using 3 tables for this example, there is in fact about 10 - 20 tables all structured the same):

```
SELECT COUNT('member_id') FROM blogs WHERE member_id=3 LIMIT 1;
SELECT COUNT('member_id') FROM articles WHERE member_id=3 LIMIT 1;
SELECT COUNT('member_id') FROM posts WHERE member_id=3 LIMIT 1;
```

You see the repetition? Is there any way of condensing that down to 1 query for example (doubt this works):

```
SELECT COUNT(blogs.'member_id') as total_blogs, 
COUNT(articles.'member_id') as total_articles, 
COUNT(posts.'member_id') as total_posts  
FROM blogs,articles,posts WHERE member_id=3 LIMIT 1;
```

P.S. Tried searching stackoverflow and google but keep getting things about using COUNT(*) or using groups, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Works,

```
SELECT  
(SELECT COUNT('member_id') FROM blogs WHERE member_id=3) as total_blogs,
(SELECT COUNT('member_id') FROM articles WHERE member_id=3) as total_articles,
(SELECT COUNT('member_id') FROM posts WHERE member_id=3) as total_posts
```

and gives you all info in only one record

Comment: This looks good, will try this in a bit and if it works, brilliant! Is there any disadvantage to using sub queries? Regarding the slow query log, would that count the WHOLE query as 1, or would that count as 3 queries to the slow log?

Comment: it counts as only one query. and it works [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/366bd/4)

Comment: in fact is an advantage, as there is only one interprocess comunication, and only one query preparation and execution. Anyway I guess that the mesured diference may be by N but insignificant.

Comment: Just for your records incase you're interested... one similar query, using indexes on my comp takes about 0.001 second, for SIX similar queries combined using the method in this answer, they all take just 0.0025 seconds! So quite a bit faster :)

Comment: check my other anwser here for multiple records selection in one single query. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM(
    SELECT member_id FROM blogs
    UNION ALL
    SELECT member_id FROM articles
    UNION ALL
    SELECT member_id FROM posts
) AS activity
WHERE member_id=3
GROUP BY member_id
```

Sqlfiddle demonstration: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/366bd/2

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I add here a second solution that admit multiple selection of IDs in a single query

```
SELECT m.member_id, 
       COALESCE(blogs.total_blogs,0)       as total_blogs, 
       COALESCE(articles.total_articles,0) as total_articles, 
       COALESCE(posts.total_posts,0)       as total_posts
FROM   members  m     -- I guess this table exists 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT member_id, COUNT('member_id') as total_blogs    FROM blogs    GROUP BY member_id) as blogs     on m.member_id = blogs.member_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT member_id, COUNT('member_id') as total_articles FROM articles GROUP BY member_id) as articles  on m.member_id = articles.member_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT member_id, COUNT('member_id') as total_posts    FROM posts    GROUP BY member_id) as posts     on m.member_id = posts.member_id
where m.member_id in (3,4,5)
```

fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/55c0b/1)

Comment: This doesn't look as simple or as quick as the previous answer?

Comment: yes, but gives you the posibility to have serveral records selected at once.

Comment: That's one hell of a query! Think i'll give that a miss as it pretty much instantly means a programmer is almost required to be a pro in MySQL to understand that completely and since i don't need that extra functionality i'll give it a miss ;) while i can "just" follow through that in my head, it don't mean others will, but thanks anyway.

Comment: well that's why it is here apart. Good luck